# Multilevel Modeling and Alternatives for Repeated Measures Design

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, controlling-for-a-variable, nested-models

I am conducting a study on the effect of different characteristics of urban space on human physiological response.  The study is a "repeated measures" design.  For this example, each of 5 participants is exposed to 8 virtual reality urban scenes (in a unique order) for one minute each scene, and their physiological responses are recorded (40 total cases). The example data set is displayed here to show the set up of the repeated measures design, where each participants's heart data is nested within a single HRV dependent variable.  Two predictor variables, SIZE (square feet) and SHAPE (ratio), are also displayed, as well as a proposed CONTROL variable to address significant differences in each participant's individual physiology (average of their 8 HRV responses).
[image]

3 questions:

1. The HRV data appears to be multilevel (2 LEVELS: individual participant and all participants grouped together).  Would adding an HRV CONTROL variable (PHYSIO) allow the use of other models, such as multiple linear regression, and mitigate a need for multilevel modeling?
2. I've seen articles that discuss using a Repeated Measures ANOVA (MANOVA, etc).  Would this statistical approach be appropriate for the described study design?
3. Would multilevel modeling be the only appropriate way to analyze this data?

Thank you!

Comment: Take at least a quick look at https://fharrell.com/post/re

Comment: With experiments like this, we often include individual as a random effect in a linear mixed model. Then your fixed effects would be SPACE-ID, HRV, SIZE, and SHAPE.

Comment: There are certainly alternatives to a multilevel model, but just adding PHYSIO as a predictor would not make it OK to use a single-level OLS regression. But if you're not interested in level 1 - level 1 effects (e.g. how size and shape predict HRV within individuals, just between), one alternative is a single-level multiple regression with id-clustered standard errors.

Comment: Thank you JLinsta and Sointu.  I will check out your recommendations.

Comment: Don't think you need the PHYSIO variable, since RMANOVA (repeat. measures ANOVA) will estimate within-subject (W) mean, the between-subject (B) means, and the BE interaction term.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the data you shared, there are clearly differences in subjects in their mean levels of HRV. This suggests that you need to account for person in some meaningful way. The main challenge is that you do not have a lot of subjects, so you have to think about approaches that can deal with small sample sizes. This [article](https://doi.org/10.1080/00273171.2017.1344538) by McNeish gets into small sample size issues with mixed effects or multilevel models. And this one [addresses](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/298058717_Modeling_Clustered_Data_with_Very_Few_Clusters) other modeling options besides multilevel models.

These are the options I would consider:

1. Perhaps the most painless is what McNeish and Stapleton call the fixed effects model. This is literally an OLS with dummy variables for each subject. One of the main problem with fixed effects models is that you cannot include between-subjects predictors (e.g., biological sex). However, you do not show any such variables in the image, so you are good.
2. The second option is a random intercept model. Because of the small sample size, you would need to use REML estimation (the default with R's `lmer`) and use the Kenward-Roger correction (found in the `lmertest` package in R).
3. As detailed in the second linked paper, you could use GEE with a small sample size correction.

Unless GEE is very common in your field, I would probably go with either option 1 or 2.